# Sound level too low in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: sound

I switched from Windows to Ubuntu.
The sound level is very low in Ubuntu.
Please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Go to System Settings -> Sound and check "Allow louder than 100%"

[image]

Comment: On windows, the volume is much greater and with no distortion. With ubuntu on this Gigabyte Aero 14, anything over 110% is distorted, and still sound lower than on windows :(